# h2 database - how to copy a xxx.mv.db file with a locked on

Tags: copy, h2

If you try to copy a file(xxx.mv.db) while h2db is running,

*the process will not be able to access it because another process has locked a portion of the file.*

An error occurs. I want to copy the file ignoring this error, but is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It was solved with 'backup to /path' of h2db.